# Are returned objects copied?

Tags: java, performance, reference

Say I have the following code:

```
Frame process(Frame input) {
 if (rareEvent) {
  input = new Frame();
 }
 input.bytes[0] = 255;
 return input;
}

//Elsewhere...
Frame example = new Frame();
example.bytes[0] = 127;
example = process(example);
```

Obviously, in the rare event that the `input` Frame object is recreated, it won't be the the exact same object. However, the end goal is that, under normal circumstances (`rareEvent` registers false), the Frame's `bytes` property will never be fully copied. This is because, in the actual scenario, it will be millions of bytes long, in a very time-sensitive operation.

In this particular case, I'm not too concerned about whether the rest of the object is truly identical, only its properties. But, for the sake of completion, I may as well inquire to both: If an object passed as a parameter is then returned, is it the *exact* same (==) object? And in my particular case, will the object's properties avoid any costly copying?

Answer (score 5):

Only an object's reference is returned, i.e. it isn't copied.  Primitive values (int, double, etc) are copied, however.

Answer (score -2):

use    `return this;`

Therefore:

```
    Frame process(Frame input) {
        if (rareEvent) {
            input = new Frame();
        }
        input.bytes[0] = 255;
        return this;
    }
```

This would return as an object because of: `this`